# Glue PySpark kernel not showing in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, kernel, aws-glue

I have a Window 10 VDI and have set-up AWS Glue Interactive session using [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/interactive-sessions.html).  Python version set-up for this is Python 3.9.7

When I start the notebook from command prompt, I see the various kernels in the browser

[image]

I have VSCode ( updated to v1.77 ) and have installed the Python and Jupyter extensions as well and trying to set-up VSCode to use the Glue Interactive sessions using [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/interactive-sessions-vscode.html) .

In VSCode, I do not see Glue PySpark as kernel Option, though see Glue Spark.  I have also added python path the kernel.json as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73994337/cannot-find-pyspark-kernel-aws-glue-interactive-sessions-with-vscode)

But I still do not see Glue PySpark as an option in VSCode.  Am I missing any set-up ?

[image]

Comment: Possibly useful: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-kernel-management#_jupyter-kernels

Comment: Thanks.  I now somehow got that to work.  My next attempt is to use jupyter notebook server in VSCode.  I will open another question ( or should I update the same question ?)

Comment: write your new question in a new question post, and write up the solution you found in an answer post here (see also [answer]) :)

Comment: Thanks.  The reason I did not write that as an answer, because I just uninstalled and reinstalled the Python and Jupyter extensions.  Wasn't sure, if that was the actual reason, or other trial and errors I was doing fixed it.   Wasn't anything specific that made it work.  The github link that had in the question is definitely required though.  Let me know, if I should still post about uninstall and reinstall part.   Also,   this is the new question. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75981078/how-to-set-up-jupyter-server-in-vscode - Thanks

Comment: what github link are you referring to?

Comment: I just realised I had put link to the SO question that had github link.  This is the github link - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/8286 -  in this SO question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73994337/cannot-find-pyspark-kernel-aws-glue-interactive-sessions-with-vscode - which was on the same subject

Comment: This doesn't answer your questions, but I went the route of using a dockerized glue container over the interactive sessions.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-libraries.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by adding the below information found at the link [Pyspark Kernel not showing](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/8286)

```
{
  "argv": [
    "D:\\venvs3\\.venv\\Scripts\\python.exe", <-- Full path to python from venv 
    "-m",
    "aws_glue_interactive_sessions_kernel.glue_pyspark.GlueKernel",
    "-f",
    "{connection_file}"
  ],
  "display_name": "PySpark",
  "language": "python"
}
```

I also uninstalled and reinstalled the set-up a few times as trial and error, but don't know if that made any difference.  The only reason I am mentioning it here is - during that process I changed different versions for packages and also installing some of them as --user as I was getting permissions issues otherwise.

That may or may not have anything to do with why it started working, but the above update to kernel.json is definitely needed.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the above mentioned changed, I also had to change the language to "scala" which does not make sense but helped to get Glue PySpark in VSCode.
`"language": "scala"`