# VS Code Jupyter error: "Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout."

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-server

I have Jupyter running from commandline and can execute the notebook in browser.  Now I want to use the same url in VSCode as Existing Jupyter Server.  What setup do I need to do inside VSCode to get it to work ?

[image]

I have started the notebook in VSCode Terminal and trying to set-up the url as http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=tokenvalue

[image]

When I try to execute the cell below, it comes back after a long time with an error.  The logs are huge, so haven't added it here.  Please let me know, if I should attach the full log

```
%profile saml
%idle_timeout 15
```

Error

```
Failed to start the Kernel. 
Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
View Jupyter log for further details.
```

[image]
[image]

Beginning of the log

```
This part is removed from here to keep the char limit, 
but has been added below in the cleaned up log
```

If I try to use it again - http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=tokenvalue - get this error

[image]

> A Jupyter Server with this URL already exists

Logs reduced to 400 lines from 1575 line

```
Visual Studio Code (1.77.1, undefined, desktop)
Jupyter Extension Version: 2023.3.1000892223.
Python Extension Version: 2023.6.0.
No workspace folder opened.
User belongs to experiment group 'jupyterEnhancedDataViewer'
User belongs to experiment group 'jupyterTest'
info 08:02:10.068: LSP Notebooks experiment is enabled
warn 08:02:10.902: No interpreter with path h\Software\Python3.9\python found in Python API, will convert Uri path to string as Id h\Software\Python3.9\python
info 08:02:11.220: Checking for server existence.
info 08:02:11.220: Checking for server existence.
info 08:02:11.222: Connecting to server
info 08:02:11.222: Connecting to server
info 08:02:11.223: Connecting remote server kernel http://localhost:8888/
Connecting to Jupyter server at http://localhost:8888/
info 08:02:11.223: Connecting remote server kernel http://localhost:8888/
Connecting to Jupyter server at http://localhost:8888/
info 08:02:11.223: Creating server with url : http://localhost:8888/
info 08:02:11.228: Creating server with url : http://localhost:8888/
info 08:02:11.292: Server started.
info 08:02:11.292: Server started.
info 08:02:11.292: Creating server with url : http://localhost:8888/
info 08:02:11.292: Creating server with url : http://localhost:8888/
warn 08:02:11.655: No interpreter with path h:\Software\Python3.9\python found in Python API, will convert Uri path to string as Id h:\Software\Python3.9\python
error 08:02:16.678: Error fetching remote kernels: [t [Error]: Forbidden
    at t.create (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:2:68133)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async t.listRunning (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:2:55998)
    at async jg.getRunningKernels (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:17:237503)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Wg.listKernelsFromConnection (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:17:248107)] {
  ( This is ---B--- in below lines)
  response: L [Response] {
    size: 0,
    timeout: 0,
    [Symbol(Body internals)]: { body: [PassThrough], disturbed: true, error: null },
    [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
      url: 'http://localhost:8888/api/kernels?1681128131298',
      status: 403,
      statusText: 'Forbidden',
      headers: [T [Headers]],
      counter: 0
    }
  },
  traceback: ''
}
error 08:02:16.782: UniversalRemoteKernelFinder: Failed to get kernels without cache [t [Error]: Forbidden
    at t.create (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:2:68133)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async t.listRunning (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:2:55998)
    at async jg.getRunningKernels (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:17:237503)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Wg.listKernelsFromConnection (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:17:248107)] {
---B---
}
error 08:02:16.782: SessionManager:getKernelSpecs failure:  [Error: Poll (@jupyterlab/services:KernelSpecManager#specs) is disposed.
    at e.dispose (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:2:171555)
    at u.dispose (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:2:62984)
    at jg.dispose (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:17:236617)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Wg.listKernelsFromConnection (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:17:248904)]
warn 08:02:17.328: Failed to get activated env vars for h:\Software\Python3.9\python.exe in 7034ms
info 08:02:17.732: Process Execution: > h:\Software\Python3.9\python.exe -c "import site;print("USER_BASE_VALUE");print(site.USER_SITE);print("USER_BASE_VALUE");"
> h:\Software\Python3.9\python.exe -c "import site;print("USER_BASE_VALUE");print(site.USER_SITE);print("USER_BASE_VALUE");"
info 08:02:28.947: Process Execution: > h:\Software\Python3.9\python.exe -m pip list
> h:\Software\Python3.9\python.exe -m pip list
warn 08:02:54.058: Disposing old controller startUsingLocalKernelSpec:'.undefined.aws_glue_interactive_sessions_kernel.glue_pyspark.gluekernel.h:\Software\Python3.9\python.h:\Software\Python3.9\python.-m#aws_glue_interactive_sessions_kernel.glue_pyspark.gluekernel' for view = 'jupyter-notebook'
warn 08:02:54.059: Disposing old controller startUsingLocalKernelSpec:'.undefined.aws_glue_interactive_sessions_kernel.glue_pyspark.gluekernel.h:\Software\Python3.9\python.h:\Software\Python3.9\python.-m#aws_glue_interactive_sessions_kernel.glue_pyspark.gluekernel (Interactive)' for view = 'interactive'
warn 08:02:54.147: No interpreter with path h:\Software\Python3.9\python found in Python API, will convert Uri path to string as Id h:\Software\Python3.9\python
warn 08:02:54.149: No interpreter with path h:\Software\Python3.9\python found in Python API, will convert Uri path to string as Id h:\Software\Python3.9\python
info 08:03:30.145: Disposing kernel .glue_spark.python.\.python#-m#aws_glue_interactive_sessions_kernel.glue_spark.gluekernel#-f#{connection_file} for notebook Untitled-1.ipynb due to selection of another kernel or closing of the notebook
info 08:03:30.145: Dispose Kernel 'Untitled-1.ipynb' associated with 'Untitled-1.ipynb'
warn 08:03:30.338: Failed to get activated env vars for h:\Software\Python3.9\python in 142ms
info 08:03:30.738: Process Execution: > h:\Software\Python3.9\python -c "import site;print("USER_BASE_VALUE");print(site.USER_SITE);print("USER_BASE_VALUE");"
> h:\Software\Python3.9\python -c "import site;print("USER_BASE_VALUE");print(site.USER_SITE);print("USER_BASE_VALUE");"
info 08:03:33.197: Process Execution: > h:\Software\Python3.9\python -m pip list
> h:\Software\Python3.9\python -m pip list
info 08:13:07.282: Starting Jupyter Session startUsingLocalKernelSpec, .undefined.aws_glue_interactive_sessions_kernel.glue_pyspark.gluekernel.h:\Software\Python3.9\python.h:\Software\Python3.9\python.-m#aws_glue_interactive_sessions_kernel.glue_pyspark.gluekernel (Python Path: , EnvType: Unknown, EnvName: '', Version: 3.9.7 (tags/v3.9.7:1016ef3, Aug 30 2021, 20:19:38) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]) for 'Untitled-1.ipynb' (disableUI=false)
info 08:13:07.543: Launching Raw Kernel Glue PySpark # H:\Software\Python3.9\python
warn 08:13:07.739: Failed to get activated env vars for h:\Software\Python3.9\python in 455ms
info 08:13:09.584: Process Execution: > h:\Software\Python3.9\python -c "import ipykernel; print(ipykernel.__version__); print("5dc3a68c-e34e-4080-9c3e-2a532b2ccb4d"); print(ipykernel.__file__)"
> h:\Software\Python3.9\python -c "import ipykernel; print(ipykernel.__version__); print("5dc3a68c-e34e-4080-9c3e-2a532b2ccb4d"); print(ipykernel.__file__)"
warn 08:13:09.585: Failed to get activated env vars for h:\Software\Python3.9\python in 2017ms
info 08:13:10.077: Process Execution: > H:\Software\Python3.9\python -m aws_glue_interactive_sessions_kernel.glue_pyspark.GlueKernel -f ~\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-v2-17012kTAjSK5zVFV5.json
> H:\Software\Python3.9\python -m aws_glue_interactive_sessions_kernel.glue_pyspark.GlueKernel -f ~\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-v2-17012kTAjSK5zVFV5.json
info 08:13:10.077: Process Execution: cwd: h:\Software\VSCode
cwd: h:\Software\VSCode
info 08:13:52.460: ipykernel version & path 6.22.0, ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py for h:\Software\Python3.9\python
error 08:14:10.193: waitUntilUsed timed out [Error: timeout
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\151.node.js:1:17183)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)]
error 08:14:10.194: Disposing kernel process due to an error [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
    at c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:17:59931
  ---C---
    ( This is --- in below lines)

  category: 'timeout',
  kernelConnectionMetadata: ca {
    kind: 'startUsingLocalKernelSpec',
    kernelSpec: cs {
      specFile: 'c:\\ProgramData\\jupyter\\kernels\\glue_pyspark\\kernel.json',
      interpreterPath: undefined,
      isRegisteredByVSC: undefined,
      name: 'undefined.aws_glue_interactive_sessions_kernel.glue_pyspark.gluekernel',
      argv: [Array],
      language: 'python',
      executable: 'H:\\Software\\Python3.9\\python',
      display_name: 'Glue PySpark',
      metadata: [Object],
      env: undefined,
      interrupt_mode: undefined
    },
    interpreter: {
      id: 'H:\\SOFTWARE\\PYTHON3.9\\PYTHON',
      sysPrefix: 'h:\\Software\\Python3.9',
      envPath: undefined,
      displayPath: [E],
      envName: '',
      uri: [E],
      displayName: '',
      envType: 'Unknown',
      isCondaEnvWithoutPython: false,
      version: [Object]
    },
    id: '.undefined.aws_glue_interactive_sessions_kernel.glue_pyspark.gluekernel.h:\\Software\\Python3.9\\python.h:\\Software\\Python3.9\\python.-m#aws_glue_interactive_sessions_kernel.glue_pyspark.gluekernel'
  }
}
error 08:14:10.196: 
info 08:14:10.196: Dispose Kernel process 2976.
error 08:14:10.631: Kernel Launcher. launch, Class name = ah, completed in 63347ms, has a falsy return value, Arg 1: {"id":".undefined.aws_glue_interactive_sessions_kernel.glue_pyspark.gluekernel.h:\\Software\\Python3.9\\python.h:\\Software\\Python3.9\\python.-m#aws_glue_interactive_sessions_kernel.glue_pyspark.gluekernel","kernelSpec":{"specFile":"c:\\ProgramData\\jupyter\\kernels\\glue_pyspark\\kernel.json","name":"undefined.aws_glue_interactive_sessions_kernel.glue_pyspark.gluekernel","argv":["H:\\Software\\Python3.9\\python","-m","aws_glue_interactive_sessions_kernel.glue_pyspark.GlueKernel","-f","{connection_file}"],"language":"python","executable":"H:\\Software\\Python3.9\\python","display_name":"Glue PySpark","metadata":{"vscode":{"originalSpecFile":"c:\\ProgramData\\jupyter\\kernels\\glue_pyspark\\kernel.json","originalDisplayName":"Glue PySpark"}}},"interpreter":{"id":"H:\\SOFTWARE\\PYTHON3.9\\PYTHON","sysPrefix":"h:\\Software\\Python3.9","displayPath":"h:\\Software\\Python3.9\\python","envName":"","displayName":"","envType":"Unknown","isCondaEnvWithoutPython":false,"version":{"major":3,"minor":9,"patch":7,"raw":"3.9.7 (tags/v3.9.7:1016ef3, Aug 30 2021, 20:19:38) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]"},"path":"h:\\Software\\Python3.9\\python"},"kind":"startUsingLocalKernelSpec"}, Arg 2: 60000, Arg 3: "Untitled-1.ipynb", Arg 4: "h:\\Software\\VSCode", Arg 5: <argument cannot be serialized for logging> [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
    at c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:17:59931
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
    at async th.launch (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:17:59973)] {
}
error 08:14:10.632: Failed to connect raw kernel session: Error: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
warn 08:14:10.633: Error occurred while trying to start the kernel, options.disableUI=false [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
---
warn 08:14:10.636: Kernel Error, context = start [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
---
warn 08:14:10.764: Failed to get activated env vars for h:\Software\Python3.9\python in 127ms
info 08:14:11.027: Process Execution: > h:\Software\Python3.9\python -c "import ipykernel;print('6af208d0-cb9c-427f-b937-ff563e17efdf')"
> h:\Software\Python3.9\python -c "import ipykernel;print('6af208d0-cb9c-427f-b937-ff563e17efdf')"
info 08:14:47.860: Dispose Kernel 'Untitled-1.ipynb' associated with 'Untitled-1.ipynb'
error 08:14:47.864: Error in execution [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
---
error 08:14:47.869: Error in execution (get message for cell) [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
---
info 13:08:13.815: Creating server with url : http://localhost:8888/
---H---
---B---
}
error 13:08:13.898: SessionManager:getKernelSpecs failure:  [Error: Poll (@jupyterlab/services:KernelSpecManager#specs) is disposed.
---D---
error 13:08:13.898: UniversalRemoteKernelFinder: Failed to get kernels without cache [t [Error]: Forbidden
    at t.create (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:2:68133)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async t.listRunning (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:2:55998)
    at async jg.getRunningKernels (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:17:237503)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Wg.listKernelsFromConnection (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:17:248107)] {
---B---
}
info 13:08:18.293: Creating server with url : http://localhost:8888/
---H---
---B---
}
error 13:08:18.360: UniversalRemoteKernelFinder: Failed to get kernels without cache [t [Error]: Forbidden
    at t.create (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:2:68133)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async t.listRunning (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:2:55998)
    at async jg.getRunningKernels (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:17:237503)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Wg.listKernelsFromConnection (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:17:248107)] {
---B---
}
error 13:08:18.360: SessionManager:getKernelSpecs failure:  [Error: Poll (@jupyterlab/services:KernelSpecManager#specs) is disposed.
---D---
info 13:08:24.870: Creating server with url : http://localhost:8888/
---H---
---B---
}
error 13:08:24.923: SessionManager:getKernelSpecs failure:  [Error: Poll (@jupyterlab/services:KernelSpecManager#specs) is disposed.
---D---
error 13:08:24.923: UniversalRemoteKernelFinder: Failed to get kernels without cache [t [Error]: Forbidden
    at t.create (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:2:68133)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async t.listRunning (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:2:55998)
    at async jg.getRunningKernels (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:17:237503)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Wg.listKernelsFromConnection (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:17:248107)] {
---B---
}
info 13:14:43.594: Creating server with url : http://localhost:8888/
---G---
> H:\Software\Python3.9\python -m aws_glue_interactive_sessions_kernel.glue_pyspark.GlueKernel -f ~\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-v2-170120XWX0Ll1cI1a.json
info 13:14:55.599: Process Execution: cwd: h:\Software\VSCode
cwd: h:\Software\VSCode
info 13:15:35.722: ipykernel version & path 6.22.0, ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py for h:\Software\Python3.9\python
error 13:15:55.613: waitUntilUsed timed out [Error: timeout
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\151.node.js:1:17183)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)]
error 13:15:55.614: Disposing kernel process due to an error [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
---
error 13:15:55.614: 
info 13:15:55.614: Dispose Kernel process 16360.
---E---
---
error 13:15:56.557: Failed to connect raw kernel session: Error: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
warn 13:15:56.560: Error occurred while trying to start the kernel, options.disableUI=false [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
---
warn 13:15:56.560: Kernel Error, context = start [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
---
warn 13:15:56.746: Failed to get activated env vars for h:\Software\Python3.9\python in 179ms
info 13:15:57.051: Process Execution: > h:\Software\Python3.9\python -c "import ipykernel;print('6af208d0-cb9c-427f-b937-ff563e17efdf')"
> h:\Software\Python3.9\python -c "import ipykernel;print('6af208d0-cb9c-427f-b937-ff563e17efdf')"
info 13:16:39.387: Dispose Kernel 'Untitled-1.ipynb' associated with 'Untitled-1.ipynb'
error 13:16:39.391: Error in execution [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
---
error 13:16:39.393: Error in execution (get message for cell) [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
---
info 13:17:35.264: Loading webview. View is notset
info 13:17:35.266: Loading web view...
info 13:17:35.267: Webview panel created.
---G---
> H:\Software\Python3.9\python -m aws_glue_interactive_sessions_kernel.glue_pyspark.GlueKernel -f ~\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-v2-17012N7jVO5qT8RFm.json
info 13:18:02.829: Process Execution: cwd: h:\Software\VSCode
cwd: h:\Software\VSCode
info 13:18:38.511: ipykernel version & path 6.22.0, ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py for h:\Software\Python3.9\python
error 13:19:02.843: waitUntilUsed timed out [Error: timeout
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\151.node.js:1:17183)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)]
error 13:19:02.843: Disposing kernel process due to an error [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
---
error 13:19:02.846: 
info 13:19:02.846: Dispose Kernel process 10808.
---E---
---
error 13:19:03.296: Failed to connect raw kernel session: Error: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
warn 13:19:03.297: Error occurred while trying to start the kernel, options.disableUI=false [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
---
warn 13:19:03.297: Kernel Error, context = start [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
---
warn 13:19:03.378: Failed to get activated env vars for h:\Software\Python3.9\python in 80ms
info 13:19:03.624: Process Execution: > h:\Software\Python3.9\python -c "import ipykernel;print('6af208d0-cb9c-427f-b937-ff563e17efdf')"
> h:\Software\Python3.9\python -c "import ipykernel;print('6af208d0-cb9c-427f-b937-ff563e17efdf')"
info 13:19:40.988: Dispose Kernel 'Untitled-1.ipynb' associated with 'Untitled-1.ipynb'
error 13:19:40.990: Error in execution [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
---
error 13:19:40.991: Error in execution (get message for cell) [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
---
info 15:49:20.417: Creating server with url : http://vxabcsv9p100288:8888/
warn 15:49:20.462: Uri verification error [FetchError: request to http://vxabcsv9p100288:8888/api/kernels?1681156160460 failed, reason: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:2:1139049)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at onerror (h:\Software\VSCode\resources\app\node_modules.asar\vscode-proxy-agent\node_modules\http-proxy-agent\node_modules\agent-base\dist\src\index.js:115:21)
    at callbackError (h:\Software\VSCode\resources\app\node_modules.asar\vscode-proxy-agent\node_modules\http-proxy-agent\node_modules\agent-base\dist\src\index.js:134:17)]
error 15:49:20.484: SessionManager:getKernelSpecs failure:  [Error: Poll (@jupyterlab/services:KernelSpecManager#specs) is disposed.
    at e.dispose (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:2:171555)
    at u.dispose (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:2:62984)
    at jg.dispose (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\extension.node.js:17:236617)
  ---C---
info 15:51:45.117: Creating server with url : http://127.0.0.1:8888/ - 6 times
error 15:52:15.159: SessionManager cannot enumerate kernelspecs. Returning a default kernel. Specs {}.
---G---
> H:\Software\Python3.9\python -m aws_glue_interactive_sessions_kernel.glue_pyspark.GlueKernel -f ~\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-v2-17012A4KNPW5hKP7p.json
info 15:53:13.573: Process Execution: cwd: h:\Software\VSCode
cwd: h:\Software\VSCode
info 15:54:07.484: ipykernel version & path 6.22.0, ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py for h:\Software\Python3.9\python
error 15:54:13.584: waitUntilUsed timed out [Error: timeout
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\151.node.js:1:17183)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)]
error 15:54:13.585: Disposing kernel process due to an error [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
---
error 15:54:13.585: 
info 15:54:13.585: Dispose Kernel process 18928.
---E---
---
error 15:54:14.135: Failed to connect raw kernel session: Error: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
warn 15:54:14.136: Error occurred while trying to start the kernel, options.disableUI=false [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
---
warn 15:54:14.137: Kernel Error, context = start [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
---
warn 15:54:14.293: Failed to get activated env vars for h:\Software\Python3.9\python in 155ms
info 15:54:14.585: Process Execution: > h:\Software\Python3.9\python -c "import ipykernel;print('6af208d0-cb9c-427f-b937-ff563e17efdf')"
> h:\Software\Python3.9\python -c "import ipykernel;print('6af208d0-cb9c-427f-b937-ff563e17efdf')"
info 15:54:54.767: Dispose Kernel 'Untitled-1.ipynb' associated with 'Untitled-1.ipynb'
error 15:54:54.770: Error in execution [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
---
error 15:54:54.771: Error in execution (get message for cell) [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
---
info 17:30:32.533: Creating server with url : http://127.0.0.1:8888/
info 17:30:48.428: Creating server with url : http://127.0.0.1:8888/
info 17:30:51.802: Creating server with url : http://127.0.0.1:8888/
error 17:31:02.578: SessionManager cannot enumerate kernelspecs. Returning a default kernel. Specs {}.
---G---
> H:\Software\Python3.9\python -m aws_glue_interactive_sessions_kernel.glue_pyspark.GlueKernel -f ~\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-v2-17012oYCcemAuJlNh.json
info 17:31:53.692: Process Execution: cwd: h:\Software\VSCode
cwd: h:\Software\VSCode
info 17:32:41.714: ipykernel version & path 6.22.0, ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py for h:\Software\Python3.9\python
error 17:32:53.708: waitUntilUsed timed out [Error: timeout
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.3.1000892223\out\151.node.js:1:17183)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)]
error 17:32:53.709: Disposing kernel process due to an error [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
---
error 17:32:53.709: 
info 17:32:53.709: Dispose Kernel process 7940.
---E---
---
error 17:32:58.743: Failed to connect raw kernel session: Error: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
warn 17:32:58.745: Error occurred while trying to start the kernel, options.disableUI=false [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
---
warn 17:32:58.745: Kernel Error, context = start [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
---
warn 17:32:58.953: Failed to get activated env vars for h:\Software\Python3.9\python in 207ms
info 17:32:59.275: Process Execution: > h:\Software\Python3.9\python -c "import ipykernel;print('6af208d0-cb9c-427f-b937-ff563e17efdf')"
> h:\Software\Python3.9\python -c "import ipykernel;print('6af208d0-cb9c-427f-b937-ff563e17efdf')"
info 17:33:43.813: Dispose Kernel 'Untitled-1.ipynb' associated with 'Untitled-1.ipynb'
error 17:33:43.819: Error in execution [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
---
error 17:33:43.821: Error in execution (get message for cell) [Jp [Error]: Unable to start Kernel 'Glue PySpark' due to connection timeout. 
---
```

Comment: The urls are already in the images - I only changed the token value - is that what you are asking or you mean put those as text in the question?  Also, do I need to add the full log - it is more than 1500 lines

Comment: if you look at the full log and it seems to contain completely irrelevant info, then don't show it. If you're not sure, consider showing it. It can always be edited out if found not to actually be relevant by an answerer. Note that there is a post size limit (IIRC, 3000 characters)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I toyed around with Jupyter in VSCode and maybe it's just the way I was doing it, but VSCode would run it's own Jupyter server instead of connecting to an existing one. I think that's why you're getting the "A Jupyter Server with this URL already exists." Because VSCode is attempting to start a second instance but port 8888 is already in use. Try disabling your command line instance and try again in VSCode. I bet it'll work, but you'll probably see a different set of notebooks (or none if it's brand new).

Comment: Thanks.  I will go through the log and see if anything seems repeated and add more of the log

Comment: @CoreyOgburn - The first time I try it, it seems to take it but when I run the cell, it generates the error I have in the question.  I get that error, only if I try to set it up again

Comment: @user - I have tried to add cleaned-up log - have removed the repeated occurrences and indicated them as ---A---, ---B---, etc.   Please let me know, if I should clean it up more.  I have tried to keep the information, but removed repetition.  Does that give you a clue as to what I need to do or what I am doing wrong?  Thanks

Comment: no idea. wait for someone knowledgeable to come answer. place a bounty if you want. ([/help/no-one-answers](/help/no-one-answers))